# How to plot line chart with series data in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a line chart with Highcharts along with navigation control, but in my example I can only see points. Please help

My chart options

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            lineWidth: 10,
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 1,
                y: -6,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.series.name;
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 10
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        formatter: function () {
            var str = '';
            str += 'Task: ' + this.series.name + '<br>';
            str += 'Start Time: ' + this.point.start_time + '<br>';
            str += 'End Time: ' + this.point.end_time + '<br>';
            str += 'Throughput: ' + this.point.y + '<br>';
            return str;
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

**Update**

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ej7moojs/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are actual creating a new series for each datapoint. So currently you effectively have 4 lines, with a single point on each line. Hence why you don't see any lines (as lines need 2 or more points).

What you need to do is create a single series with multiple data points. Something like this:

```
var series = [{
    "name": "Territory_Out",
        "data": [{
        "x": 1147651200000,
            "y": 33.1,
            "start_time": "14-05-2006 00:00:00",
            "end_time": "15-05-2006 00:00:00"
    }, {
        "x": 1147737600000,
            "y": 450,
            "start_time": "15-05-2006 00:00:00",
            "end_time": "16-05-2006 00:00:00"
    }, {
        "x": 1147737600000,
            "y": 400,
            "start_time": "15-05-2006 00:00:00",
            "end_time": "16-05-2006 00:00:00"
    }, {
        "x": 1147824000000,
            "y": 77.67,
            "start_time": "16-05-2006 00:00:00",
            "end_time": "17-05-2006 00:00:00"
    }]
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. So I modified to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ej7moojs/6/) but in this how to show task name without clutering the chart if there are too many data points (tasks)? As on `16 May` task name is overlapping

Comment: @Ricky: I suggest you ask that as a new question. I don't actually know the solution off the top of my head. It might be better to not show them at all, and just have the info displayed on hover